# Can I boot OS X or Windows Boot Camp from an external USB Type-C drive?

Tags: bootcamp, startup, external-disk, usb

Currently I boot OS X and Windows Boot Camp from an external Thunderbolt HDD. LaCie just announced a new external USB-C (USB 3.1) hard drive enclosure. Will I be able to boot OS X or Windows Boot Camp from this or any other external USB-C HDD on the new MacBook?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the just announced new MacBook isn't yet generally available there are very few people, if any, that can say they've actually connected a LaCie USB-C (USB 3.0) external drive to the just announced new MacBook and booted either OS X or Windows from the external drive.  That said, I'd be very shocked if one was not able to boot any OS that supports booting from an external USB device while connected to the just announced new MacBook that isn't yet generally available.  Especially considering the just announced new MacBook only has only the USB-C port (and an audio jack) for any type of physical expansion capacity it would be insane that past normal functionality was not capable.

Comment: I ask specifically about Windows Boot Camp because it does support booting from thunderbolt but not USB 3 or lower. However Wikipedia says that the alt pins on USB 3.1 could support other connections such as PCI Express.

Comment: @Steve Moser, You did not exclusively specifically ask "about Windows Boot Camp" as you explicitly and specifically said "_Will I be able to boot OS X or Windows Boot Camp from this or any other external USB-C HDD on the new MacBook?_" and my reply under the current circumstances addresses that question as you did in fact explicitly and specifically use the conjunction "**or**"!

Comment: Also note that I meant LaCie USB-C (USB 3.1) not (USB 3.0) when I originally posted this answer. I'm not going to edit the answer as the post is old enough not be be that relevant at this point.

Answer (score 0):

To me USB stays USB.

Type-C is just a physical form factor as Type-A and Type-B.

So yes it will work.

Comment: USB has different speeds for different specs. In my question I specify that I'm talking about USB 3.1.